# How to upload file using php in Ionic?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I want to upload file in Ionic. I follow [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f0oLzDazS0). But I want to upload file through php. How can I call php file?

**html code**

```
<button ion-button (click)="choose()">Upload</button>
```

**ts code**

```
choose()
  {
    this.filechooser.open().then((uri) => {
      alert(uri);

      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(uri).then((newUrl) =>{
        alert(JSON.stringify(newUrl));

        let dirPath = newUrl.nativeURL;
        let dirPathSegments = dirPath.split('/');
        dirPathSegments.pop();
        dirPath = dirPathSegments.join('/');

        this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(dirPath,newUrl.name).then((buffer =>{
          this.upload(buffer,newUrl.name);
        }));
      });
    }); 
  }

upload(buffer , name)
  { }
```

Comment: [You can't expect someone on SO to write all the code for you, surely?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upload+file+php+ionic&oq=upload+file+php+ionic&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0.3191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I can help you on uploading your file with android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

File upload using PHP,

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "Upload and move success";
} else {
echo $target_path;
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Source - https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-3/upload-image-to-the-php-server-using-ionic-3-file-transfer-and-camera-plugin

Comment: what to do on ionic side in `upload()`  function, i am already using this same php code

Comment: @user2828442 Check that source link it contains detailed tutorial

Comment: this line is confusing, in my case what will it be - `this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {`

Comment: it will be helpful if you can help me make ionic side code of both functions